# High Speed-High Resolution Image Capture with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (and Pi Camera)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi3

Is there a way to lessen the time taken by the raspberry pi 3 in capturing at least 1 image while being on the move? It’s like point and shoot setup.

Currently, what I have is that the raspberry pi 3 takes at least 2-3secs to capture 1 image with the 8-megapixel pi-camera (read-write). Since the raspberry pi is attach on a drone, being on the move while taking photo causes a blurry output (the ave. speed of the drone is around 4.5ft/sec), I can still slow it down depending in your advice.

I only need to take 1 image once my object of interest is spotted.

As much as possible I don't want to sacrifice the quality of the image since I'll be using it for another analysis.

I'm hoping that you can give me direction on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You talk about capturing an image (implying still images) and you talk about FPS (implying video). Which are you actually doing? How long do you capture for? Or how many still images do you capture? What size (bytes) and pixels are your images?

Comment: Poor choice of hardware for the the task. To make an analogy, you're trying to win a Formula 1 race driving a [Reliant Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliant_Robin). | For the motion blur, minimize the exposure rate. Running shutter probably doesn't help with a moving camera. Again, the budget hardware might be a limiting factor here. Do your research. | You seem to have started from the wrong end. Figure out your requirements. Based on that, determine the minimum specs your hardware must meet. Pick hardware accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, when I started this proj. originally it was not designed to take images while on the move but as the scope of the proj. went wider this where I got stuck. But I'n still crossing my fingers to find a way-around even if I need to sacrifice the flight speed of the drone.

Comment: I edited the question above to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This may sound blunt but you are pushing the Raspberry Pi to it's limits, reaching them, and then not wanting to implement the suggestions to work around those limits.

If you want to work with real-time, high quality images, the RPi is not the device. You would be better off working with something that has a GPU, and a lot more processing capability.

Something like [this](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825) would cut the mustard much better.